# Puppet - restrict actions per environment?

Tags: puppet

How can I restrict the puppet agent commands? I need to only allow the puppet agent to run without noop against the production branch.

- Block `puppet agent --test --environment devbranch`
- Allow `puppet agent --test --environment devbranch --noop`
- Allow `puppet agent --test --environment production`

I think some kind wizardry in auth.conf should be able to take care of this but I'm not familiar enough to do so.

Comment: I am tempted to believe that you could put a `noop = true` in the `[devbranch]` section, of the puppet.conf so it at least defaults to noop, but I haven't tried it.

Comment: @Zoredache that sounds promising. I'm using dynamic modules paths under the [main] section so it's a bit more complicated Would a noop there and a `noop=false` in production potentially work?

Comment: No idea really.  I don't have a good place to test at the moment, so you'll have to try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With thanks to @Zoredache I have managed to get this build the way I need.

I'm using the [main] section to dynamically create and manage branches and [production] to override the noop setting. I'm sure it could also be done in [agent] but I already had it started here.

```
[main]
    logdir = /var/log/puppet
    rundir = /var/run/puppet
    confdir = /puppet/$environment
    vardir = /puppet/.$environment-var
    ssldir=/etc/puppet/ssl
    environment = production
    server = puppet.domain.org
    pluginsync = true
    noop = true
    # Disable running all branches by default

[production]
    noop = false
```

EDIT: 
Looks like I spoke too soon. The noop is bleeding through. Although the syntax above is right one of the caviats I looked over won't let this work. https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/env_environments.html

> .. environments have some
>   limitations, most of which are known bugs or vagaries of
>   implementation rather than design choices.
>
> **Puppet will only read the modulepath, manifest, manifestdir, and
>   templatedir settings from environment config blocks**; other settings in
>   any of these blocks will be ignored in favor of settings in the
>   [master] or [main] blocks. (Issue 7497)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it like that, someone that have access to commandline could enforce pretty much any option.

If you want to control who can deploy what env I'd advise to use [MCollective](http://puppetlabs.com/mcollective) for running puppet. You can make pretty detailed ACLs there, and it can coordinate puppet on multiple nodes and do stuff like "deploy on 2 machines, if it doesn't fail, deploy on next 10, if it doesn't fail, deploy on rest".

Comment: I realize that it's possible to override the noop setting if desired. It's mostly a safety thing to set the default to something sensible.